# DCF77 on BeagleBone - Get Time Signal and decode it

Tags: microcontroller, beagleboneblack, real-time-clock, dcf77

I want to have a RTC on my BBB. I wired the DCF77 on the UART4. 
Can you tell me how can I read the signal of the DCF77 and decode it on the BBB ?

Thx

Comment: There is not "the DCF77". There are many DCF77 boards. Simple demodulators as well as very clever decoders. Before this can be answered you need to specify which board you are using. You also need to specify what you are running on the BBB. Linux?